# Password reset link using jwt and nodejs

Tags: node.js, jwt

This code is not working

```
          router.put('/requestpass',function(req,res){
               console.log('inside password');
               async.waterfall([
                 function(done) {
                 user.findOne({
                  email: req.query.useremail
                 }).exec(function(err, user) {
                          if (user) {
                    done(err, user);
                         } else {
                   done('User not found.');
            }
              });
},
function(user, done) {
```

create token

```
            var token= user.generateJwt();
             done(err, user, token);

},
```

// updates user object with new token and expiration date

```
             function(user, token, done) {

  user.findOneAndUpdate({ email : req.query.useremail }, { token: token, reset_password_expires: Date.now() + 86400000 }, { upsert: true, new: true }).exec(function(err, new_user) {
    if(err){console.log('error hain')}
    done(err, token, new_user);
  });
},
```

//configuring email

```
        function(token, user, done) {

  ejs.renderFile(__dirname + "../templates/url.ejs", { url: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/reset_password?token=' + token }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        var mainOptions = {
            from: 'kapilutkarsh1@gmail.com',
            to: "kapilutkarsh1@gmail.com",
            subject: 'Password Reset',
            html: data
        };
        console.log("html data >", mainOptions.html);
        transporter.sendMail(mainOptions, function (err, info) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
                }
                     });
                   }

                    });
                }
           ], function(err) {
     return res.status(422).json({ message: err });
        });
     });
```

I have made this function which will send reset password link to the user but it is not working it is showing error on user.`findOneandupdate` and then in email configuration below is function generating token

```
                 userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function() {
var expiry = new Date();
expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

return jwt.sign({
  _id: this._id,
  email: this.email,
  name: this.name,
  exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000),
        }, "MY_SECRET"); // 
         };

             that's how I have configured email 

               var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
               service: 'gmail',
                    auth: {
                  user: '**',
                    pass: '****'
                     }
                     });
```

Comment: mail is send successfully just tell me why  user.findOneAndUpdate({ email : req.query.useremail }, { token: token, reset_password_expires: Date.now() + 86400000 }, { upsert: true, new: true }).exec(function(err, new_user) {
    if(err){console.log('error hain')}
    done(err, token, new_user);
  }); is not adding two properties token and resetpassword expires

Comment: If this question is solved, please post an answer in the answer box below, not as a comment or a question/title update. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code
    // request to send smtp email containing jwt token in the URL
    router.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next){
    async.waterfall([
        function(done){
            Usermodel.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user){
                if(!user){
                    return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Invalid email!', detail: 'User does not exist'}]});
                }

                const token = jwt.sign({
                    userId: user.id,
                    username: user.username,
                    resetPasswordToken: user.resetPasswordToken
                  }, config.SECRET, { expiresIn: '1h' });

                user.resetPasswordToken = token;
                user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

                user.save(function(err){
                    done(err, token, user);
                });
            });
        },

        function(token, user, done){
            const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'Gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: 'XXXX',
                    pass: 'XXXX'
                }
            });

            const mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
                subject: 'Nodejs password reset',
                text: 'You are receiving this email. Please click on the email for password reset ' +
                      'http://' + req.headers.host + '/reset/' + token + '\n\n' + 
                      'If you did not request this, please ignore this email'
            };
            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err){
                console.log('mail sent');
                done(err, 'done');
            });
        }
    ], function(err){
        if(err) return next(err);
    });
});

// request to get and verify if the token has expired or user is invalid
router.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res){
    Usermodel.findOne({resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: {$gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user){
        if(!user) {
            return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'Invalid token!', detail: 'User does not exist'}]});
        }   
        res.json('reset', {token: req.params.token});
    });
});

// request to update the password in database if password and confirm password is matching. Also send email to user regarding successful password change
router.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res){
    async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
            Usermodel.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user){
                if(!user){`enter code here`
                    return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'error', detail: 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired'}]});
                }

                if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm){
                    user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err){
                        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
                        user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

                        user.save(function(err){
                            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                                done(err, user);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    return res.status(422).send({errors: [{title: 'error', detail: 'Password do not match'}]});
                }
            });
        },
        function(user, done){
            var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: 'Gmail',
                auth: {
                    user: 'XXXX',
                    pass: 'XXXX'
                }
            });

            var mailOptions = {
                to: user.email,
                from: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
                subject: 'Your password has been changed',
                text: 'Hello,\n\n' + 
                    'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just changed'
            };
            smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err){
                done(err);
            });
        }
    ],   function(err){
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```